# node.js c++ extension multiple cc files into one module

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

i´m playing a little bit with node.js to evaluate how a complexe c based library could be connected with node.js. This lib perform several actions with a database and nodejs shall call this functions and return the results via rest api.

While playing aroung with the examples from the [node.js](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) side, i faced a problem:

I´m trying to build one addon based on two cc files:

addon1.c:

```
#define BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION
#include <node.h>

using namespace v8;

Handle<Value> Add(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;

  if (args.Length() < 2) {
    ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("Wrong number of arguments")));
    return scope.Close(Undefined());
  }

  if (!args[0]->IsNumber() || !args[1]->IsNumber()) {
    ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("Wrong arguments")));
    return scope.Close(Undefined());
  }

  Local<Number> num = Number::New(args[0]->NumberValue() +
      args[1]->NumberValue());
  return scope.Close(num);
}

void Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("add"),
      FunctionTemplate::New(Add)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, Init)
```

addon2.c:

```
#define BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION
#include <node.h>

using namespace v8;

Handle<Value> Del(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope2;

  if (args.Length() < 2) {
    ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("Wrong number of arguments")));
    return scope2.Close(Undefined());
  }

  if (!args[0]->IsNumber() || !args[1]->IsNumber()) {
    ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("Wrong arguments")));
    return scope2.Close(Undefined());
  }    

  Local<Number> num = Number::New(args[0]->NumberValue() -
      args[1]->NumberValue());
  return scope2.Close(num);
}

void Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("del"),
      FunctionTemplate::New(Del)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, Init)
```

And my binding.gyp:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": ["addon1.cc", "addon2.cc"]
    }
  ]
}
```

calling node.gyp configure build ends with following error messages:

```
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/addon/addon2.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/addon.node
duplicate symbol __Z4InitN2v86HandleINS_6ObjectEEE in:
    Release/obj.target/addon/addon1.o
    Release/obj.target/addon/addon2.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/addon.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/opt/local/bin/node-gyp" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodejs/test2
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.26
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I hope anyone of you have a hint how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the files extension `.c` or `.cc`? It's not clear in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is pretty clear: You have a function named `Init` in both translation units (source files). As you are building a *single* module, you should have only one `Init` function.

The simple way to solve this is to remove one `Init` function, and "register" both `add` and `del` names in the remaining `Init` function.

---

Solution: In ***one*** source file you have the ***only*** `Init` function, and *declare* the missing `Add` or `Del` function (i.e. you make function prototypes):

```
// Declare function prototypes
Handle<Value> Add(const Arguments& args);
Handle<Value> Del(const Arguments& args);

// The one and only initialization function
void Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("add"),
      FunctionTemplate::New(Add)->GetFunction());
  exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("del"),
      FunctionTemplate::New(Del)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, Init)
```

Actually, you can now have this as a separate source file.

Comment: But how can i than init the method "del" without init function? I tried to rename it to init2 but same error occurs.

Comment: No that doesn´t work either. If i move the del initialization into the init funtion of addon1.c i get an error for undecalred identifier 'Del'. Moving the init function to addon2.c procudes the same error but now for identifier 'Add'

Comment: Thanks i´ve found this solution meanwhile on my own. Obviously it is not intended by the nodejs guys to split functions within the same module into seperate files.

Answer (score 1):

From your implementation I can see you are trying to implement **TWO DIFFERENT MODULES add and del**.

node.js provides different types of Addon Patterns as suggested by http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

In my opinion, what you are trying to implement can be obtained by [Wrapping C++ objects](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_wrapping_c_objects)

Comment: Hi, no i was looking for a way to have one module (addon) which has two methods (del, add) and implement each method within a seperate cpp file.

Comment: Yes, and this is possible. But not the way you are trying to implement as per the original post. If you look thoroughly into entire page, you will definitely find the answer.